# How to debug "Missing argument 1 for Skill::delskill"?

Tags: codeigniter

```
Error:  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Skill::delskill()

Filename: controllers/Skill.php

Line Number: 75

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/tatui/application/controllers/Skill.php
Line: 75
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/tatui/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
//
```

Here's code, remaining code is working perfectly

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Skill extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        
    }
     public function construct_pages($page, $data) {           
          $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
          $this->load->view('templates/footer');
      }
    // checks login using in built validation


   public function index()
    {

      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('pages/AddSkill');

    }
    public function skill_validate(){

      $this`enter code here`->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('skillid', 'skillid', 'required|max_length[15]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('skillname', 'SkillName', 'required|max_length[25]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('skilldescription', 'skilldescription', 'required|max_length[70]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('skillgroup', 'skillgroup', 'required');

      if($this->form_validation->run()){

        $this->load->model('Getskills', '', TRUE);
        $skill = $this->input->post('skillid');
        $skillExisted = $this->Getskills->getskill($skill);
        if($skillExisted){

          echo "Skill Already Existed";
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->view('pages/AddSkill');

        }
        else{
          $data = array(
          'SkillId' =>  $this->input->post('skillid'),
          'SkillDescription' => $this->input->post('skilldescription'),
          'SkillGroup' => $this->input->post('skillgroup'),
          'SkillName' => $this->input->post('skillname')
         );

         $inserted = $this->Getskills->insert_skill($data);
          if($inserted){

            echo "Inserted Successfully";
            $this->load->view('pages/AddSkill');        
          }        
          else{

            echo  "Please contact Support Team";
          }
      }

    }
    else{

       echo  "Please contact Support Team";
    }

  }
```

This portion is not working correctly?

```
  public function delskill($data) {

      $this->db->where(array('Skillid' , 'Skillname' , 'Skillgroup' , 'Skilldescription'));
      $this->db->delete('Skills');

    }

  }
```

Does anybody know the actual reason it does not work?

Comment: your last function delskill($data)  why you need ? please tell me

Comment: Message says that `$data` is not provided in link you clicked. Check your view file or view-source of rendered page to know what links are created. Second problem is in your query builer delete method. Study [this guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data) how that part of code should looks like.

Comment: Please try to use useful titles here that describe your problem, and avoid txtspk - `I have an error plz help me` creates some work for an editor to fix.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question it showing error like Missing argument 1 for Skill::delskill()
it means where ever you are calling the delskill function you are not passing any parameter into that, but you have created this function with one parameter as public function delskill($data){...}, so, you need to pass one parameter in to delskill function. But I looked on to your delskill function, there is no use of it, because you are not using that passed parameter in to that function, and that function where condition is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send default argument to method or function if you are not sure to send it always.

```
 public function delskill($data = '') {
     if (isset($data) && is_array($data)) {
         $this->db->where(array('Skillid' , 'Skillname' , 'Skillgroup' , 'Skilldescription'), $data);
         $this->db->delete('Skills');
     }
}
```

Note: As per your code, you're deleting from multiple column. If you are sending blank data as args and it executes query you will face loss of data problem. make sure you always send valid deletion request, Have a safe SQL.